# Installing old packages on RStudio-hosted Shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio-server, install.packages

I am trying to install several packages on the RStudio-hosted Shiny Server, but these packages run with at least R version 3.0.0. A possible solution that I found on the Internet:

`download.file('http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/devtools/devtools_1.1.tar.gz', destfile='devtools_1.1.tar.gz')`

`install.packages('devtools_1.1.tar.gz', type='source', repos=NULL)`

`unlink('devtools_1.1.tar.gz')`

does not work and I get the following error:

> Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘devtools_1.1.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 2.15.3)

How could I modify this code in such a way that I am able to install the devtools package?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: an example here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/shiny-discuss/7yDBJ8jM4NU/discussion

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the quick solution would involve looking into the specifics of the packages you want, but as a solution to the larger problem, checkout [Packrat](https://github.com/rstudio/packrat), which can be used to bundle R packages (of whatever version) in your application before deploying.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. I will take a look at you suggestion! But can you explain to me why I cannot install a package on the RStudio Server while I can install the same package on the same version of my local RStudio?